# QGIS change geometry type in shapefile

Tags: qgis, geometry, merge

I have 7 shapefiles which I would like to combine using the 'Merge shapefiles' function in QGIS.  I got the error message that the shapefiles must all be the same geometry.  I checked this, one shapefile has the geometry 'WKB type - PolygonZ' - I think this was a shapefile created when I used the Vector-dissolve function.  All the other files have the geometry 'Polygon'. How do I change the geometry of this shapefile - or is it a case of recreating and re-saving the original shapefile?

Comment: _Right-click_ the layer and select `Save As...`. In the **Layer Options** section, there is a dropdown menu for `SHPT`. Select _Polygon_, this should re-save the polygon layer without the z-dimension.

Answer (score 8):

From @Joseph comment :

> Right-click the layer and select Save As.... In the Layer Options
>   section, there is a dropdown menu for SHPT. Select Polygon, this
>   should re-save the polygon layer without the z-dimension.

[image: SHPT dropdown]

Answer (score 4):

This should work without complaint in QGIS 3.0 and greater - the output layer will be a PolygonZ type, and the Polygon input features will be upgraded to PolygonZ geometries to match.